# jQuery selecting input class not working with multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace the placeholder of a form depending on the width of the browser window:

```
<input class="form-control top-menu" type="text" placeholder="Search all products" />
```

Note that the class is `form-control top-menu`.

When I try to select it with jQuery, nothing happens:

```
var input = $("input[class=top-menu]");
```

I also tried with

```
var input = $("input[class=form-control top-menu]");
```

Same problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vfu3cdwb/6/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input.form-control.top-menu')
```

this will select only element tag input with calss form-control and top-menu

jquery use [css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to find a elements.

Comment: I forgot inverted commas, check again and try

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $("input.top-menu");
```